# How to print an array single elements of an array in a table?

Tags: javascript, html

number is of type array which stores some numbers when called addNumber function and displays that array in another table which has a row with id as "output".Right now in my single td element of table all the elements of the array are printed but i need to print single array element to single td element.
How can I achieve this?

**Html**

```
   <table>
<tr>
<td id="output"></td> // I want every element of the array to print in single //td element.right now all elements of the array are printing in first td element.
<td></td>
<td></td>
... and do on 
</tr>
    </table>

<table>
  <tr>

    <td onClick="addNumber(1)">1</td>
    <td onClick="addNumber(2)">2</td>
    <td onClick="addNumber(3)">3</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
let number = [];

function addNumber( num) {      
   number.push(num);
   console.log( number );
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = number;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give id to your `tr` and on every click append a `td` to it. Also, the value for `td` will be the `num` and not the `number` which is an array.

```js
let number = [];

function addNumber(num) {
  number.push(num);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<td>" + num + "</td>";
}

function deleteNumber() {
  number.pop();
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
   output.removeChild(output.lastChild);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="output"></tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onClick="addNumber(1)">1</td>
    <td onClick="addNumber(2)">2</td>
    <td onClick="addNumber(3)">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a onClick="deleteNumber()">Delete</a>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<td>" + num + "</td>"; this line adds a td what if I have to remove a td ?

Comment: What is the operation that triggers the delete?

Comment: press key which is left of " 0 " in the keypad. if u visit the above url

Comment: function deleteNumber() {
            number.pop();
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
            console.log('number', number);
        }

Comment: @Aditya - That url is your system url which is not accessible over net. Please update your question and add the html and the complete requirement there

Comment: sorry it was misspelled.It is "jain" insted of "jan" in the url, and it is accessible.

Comment: If we can chat on conversation then It will be helpful

Comment: @Aditya - I have updated the code  where you can delete the number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173051/discussion-between-aditya-and-nikhil-aggarwal).

Comment: @NikhilAggarawal If you can chat once I have a small doubt please

Comment: I cannot add another question till one hour, it will be a great honour :)

Comment: How to add a class on these td elements?

Comment: @NikhilAggarawal - I need some help, I have send you an inmail over linkedIn

Answer (score 0):

You need to append each result to tr; :D

```js
let number = [];

function addNumber( num) {      
   number.push(num);
   dislpayArray(number)
}

function dislpayArray(number){
    var el= document.getElementById("output");
    var output;
    number.forEach(function (item){
      output = '<td>'+item+'</td>';
   })
   el.innerHTML += output; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="output">
    
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onClick="addNumber(1)">1</td>
    <td onClick="addNumber(2)">2</td>
    <td onClick="addNumber(3)">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it would be helpful for the large table and dynamic data's

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
let number = [];
 $('#clickble td').on('click',function(){
  var value = $(this).html();
  addNumber(value);
 });
 function addNumber(num) {
  number.push(num);
  $('#output').append("<td>" +num+"</td>");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="output"></tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr id="clickble">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```